# form_for does not pass the required value when user submits blank form

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, web

I have the following form:

```
  # controller
  def edit
    @doc = HomeworkDocument.find(params[:id])
  end

  # view
  <%= form_for @doc, 
      url: student_homework_document_path(student_id: @doc.submitter_id,
                                           id: @doc.id),
      html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :file1 %>
  <%= f.file_field :file1 %>

  <%= f.label :file2 %>
  <%= f.file_field :file2 %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
```

When the user submits either one or both of `file1` and `file2`, the form works fine. However, when the user clicks submit without any file, exception is raised:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: homework_document
```

due to my strong param specification:

```
def doc_grader_params
  params.require(:homework_document)
        .permit(:file1, :file2)
end
```

The param that gets passed is (notice no `homework_document` is passed):

Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"QJirOW/HQ3sv8AR/yArW6cQ2bmvz0j5D8G6czu45lLA=",
 "commit"=>"Submit grading",
 "student_id"=>"4",
 "id"=>"21"}
```

Why does this happen and how to to include an (empty) `homework_document` hash in `param` even when the user submits blank form?

Answer (score 0):

To include an empty `homework_document` hash, you have two options:

1. Assuming you *do not* want to override the `:file1, :file2` attributes if submission is empty, add an empty `hidden_field` in the form and allow that to pass in via *strong parameters*, but do virtually nothing to the parameter. Like so:

`<%= hidden_field_tag 'homework_document[placeholder]', 'do nothing' %>`

```
def doc_grader_params
  params.require(:homework_document)
        .permit(:file1, :file2, :placeholder)
end
```

2. If you *do* want to override the attributes (erasing files if empty), place two `hidden_field`s of name `homework_document[file1]` and `homework_document[file2]` **before** the file inputs and set their value to `''`(or whatever defaults you have). Because parameters extraction gets the last occurrence of any repeated key in the query string, this should work.

This approach is similar to the check_box empty submission approach outlined in:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box